# Rerun inline scripts at end of external script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline

I built a site for a client where I have a script which moves a sidebar div below the main content when in mobile view. This script is loaded in the footer:

```js
// Move Global nav to top for mobile
$(window).on("resize", function() {
var windowSize = $(window).innerWidth();
    if(windowSize > 767){

        $(".utility-nav").insertBefore($(".global-nav"));
        $(".sidebar-secondary").insertAfter($(".subnav"));

    } else {

        $(".global-nav").insertBefore($(".utility-nav"));
        $(".sidebar-secondary").insertAfter($(".content-main"));

    }
}).resize();
```

They are adding a third party calendar which requires them to insert code snippets that include inline scripts. When these are placed in the .sidebar-secondary div, which is moved for mobile, the content disappears. I assume that, since my script is running after these have initiated, they are being canceled out.

Is there a way to just have my script rerun any inline scripts within that div?

Here is the page they are testing:
http://www.umary.edu/sandbox-training/index.php

The scripts in the left sidebar are the ones that are malfunctioning.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all the script tags within your div and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) the text inside them

```js
$('#run').click(function(){
 $('#someSideBar').find('script').each(function(){
     eval( $(this).text() ); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someSideBar">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   alert('hello');
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   alert('there');
  </script>
</div>
<input type="button" id="run" value="Run">
```

** You should research the security implications of this before proceeding.

Comment: I am out of town but will try this when I return. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your content disappears is because the `<iframe>`s that hold your content are *unloaded* when they are detached from the DOM, and *loaded* upon attaching them to the DOM again. Since the `<iframe>`s in question seem to be generated by a script, the second load yields an empty document. See this [simple DOM test-case](http://jsbin.com/layonuruya/edit?html,js,console,output) for seeing that load/unload bevhavior. As far as I can tell there is no way to move an iframe in the DOM in such a way that this behavior is prohibited.

You explicitly ask for this, but simply rerunning the inline `<script>`s may not yield the results you hope for, unless these scripts are (accidentally or purposefully) written in such a way that allows this. Be *very* careful with this sort of stuff. If there is a single `document.write()` your entire document would be overwritten. This is usually not the kind of destructive power you'd want to hand to a third party script.

- You could try rearranging your content using Flexbox and the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/order) property, so content is moved in CSS and not the DOM.
- You could try rearranging the *other* content in such a way that you don't need to move `.sidebar-secondary` in the DOM. You may need to split the secondary content block into a separate `<div role="complimentary">` (btw. that's what [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) is for). Once that is done, you can move `#content-start` before the container of `.sidebar-secondary`.

Comment: I am out of town but will try this when I return. Thank you so much!